# copy and paste for columns between two text files

Tags: text-processing

I have two text files. I need to copy columns 5-6-7 of one text file and paste these columns to another text file. For example, first column of text files as follows;

text_1:

```
E GPS41 568026000 0.000000000000000E+00 1.097676240456553E+04 -1.668403004627044E+04 1.770513486005421E+04 2.140299562139315E+00 -5.351523203487980E-01 -1.876979500368582E+00 1.714052588162549E-05 1.390618031795355E-05 8.605165964871206E-06 3.266367837880071E-09 3.392831966908295E-09 1.626218351208862E-09
```

text_2:

```
E    GPS41  0  5.68026000000000E+08  1.09767623810000E+04 -1.66840300460000E+04  1.77051348440000E+04
```

I need to copy column 5-6-7 of text_1 and paste these to text_2 as follow;

new_text:

```
E    GPS41  0  5.68026000000000E+08 1.097676240456553E+04 -1.668403004627044E+04 1.770513486005421E+04
```

Comment: Do you need to *match* the corresponding lines (based on the value of the first couple of fields, say) or is it a simple side-by-side paste of line 1 from file 1  with line 1 from file 2 and so on?

Comment: just a simple side by side paste.

Comment: So you want to *replace* fields 5-7 of `text_2` with those of `text_1`?

Comment: yes it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data appears to have inconsistent amounts of whitespace between fields, `awk` will handle it better than `cut`. So `paste` the two files together and then pick out the required fields from the composite:

```
paste text_2 text_1 | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12,$13,$14}' > new_text
```

Ex.

```
$ cat new_text 
E GPS41 0 5.68026000000000E+08 1.097676240456553E+04 -1.668403004627044E+04 1.770513486005421E+04
```

The output differs from yours only in terms of whitespace:

```
$ diff -sb your_new_text new_text 
Files your_new_text and new_text are identical
```

If you need to preserve the exact amounts of whitespace, you can change the awk `print` to a suitably formatted `printf`.

---

You can do it with `cut` and `paste` if you first squeeze the delimiters down to single spaces:

```
paste -d ' ' <(tr -s ' ' < text_2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1-4) <(tr -s ' ' < text_1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5-7) > new_text
```

Comment: Dear @steeldriver, if I want to copy column 5-6-7 of text_2 into text_1 while preserving text_1 other columns, how can you modify the code?

Comment: I will ask this as a new question.

Comment: OK - can I suggest you provide a simpler test case (with simpler, shorter fields - and preferably more than a single line)

Comment: I've asked this with the same data one min ago.